# YouTube embedded video not playing /appears locked

Tags: youtube

I’m linking to a video on my web site that’s hosted on youtube.  It was playing fine, however now it does not seem to play.  There was a flashing black circle in the upper left corner for a while.  Now when I click the play button, nothing happens.

I can say that I did add a responsive div to show what properly on mobile devices, but that did not fix it initially.  I’m not sure if I also need to wait for to come back.

Is there something I might need to change in my YouTube settings? If anyone knows what I need to do to resolve this issue, I would very much appreciate it.

```
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs">
   <center>
       <iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LohCR8Nj00?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </center>   


</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg">
 <center>
    <iframe width="280" height="160" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LohCR8Nj00?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a video once on a page apparently. i corrected the css to be responsive and now it works